# how to embed one to many sonata admin child views in ConfigeShowFields

Tags: symfony, twig, sonata-admin

I have a `one to many` relationship between account and contacts. I use sonata admin bundle

I want to display all contacts of an account in the view detail of an account ( `ConfigureShowFields` in `AccountAdmin` class)

[image: show detail account]

in class `AcountAdmin.php` i have :

```
 protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
     # .......
        ->with('Liste des contacts', array('class' => 'col-md-12'))
        ->add('contacts')
        ->end()
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do this via sonata_type_collection.

```
            ->add('contacts', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'associated_property' => 'email',
                'route' => array(
                    'name' => 'show'
                ),
                'admin_code' => 'app.admin.contacts',
            ))
```

The associated_property is the associated property found in the Contacts entity, and the admin_code is the contacts admin.

Comment: thanks you it worked for me,but it's possible to show multipe associated_property ?